# writing Swagger (openAPI) specs: securityDefinitions

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to implement HTTP Basic Auth on my Swagger page.

the [docs for securityDefinitions](https://swagger.io/specification/#securitySchemeObject) give an example:

```
type: http
scheme: basic
```

however when I add it to my YAML file like this:

```
securityDefinitions:
  type: http
  scheme: basic
```

I get an error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
type: http
scheme: basic
```

is OpenAPI 3.0 syntax (the spec you linked to is OpenAPI 3.0).

But you are using OpenAPI 2.0, so you need to use:

```yaml
securityDefinitions:
  BasicAuth:
    type: basic

security:
  - BasicAuth: []
```

Here is the OpenAPI 2.0 Spec:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#securitySchemeObject

And here's the Basic auth guide for 2.0:
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/basic-authentication/

Comment: gr8, but where do u define the user and pass for it ?